# Python with Xcode

Tags: python, xcode

I would have 2 questions:

1. I opened a python file with Xcode and it seems to have recognized it, but still the syntax coloring doesn't seem like python, so how to make it correspond ?
2. I tried to create a new Python project with Xcode following the instructions on this website: https://ericasadun.com/2016/12/04/running-python-in-xcode-step-by-step/ , but gives me "ERROR: unknown command "$(SRCROOT)/Work.py". I want to precise that it didn't give me the executable directly I had to select it myself in  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9". I tried some suggested fixes as changing the "$(SRCROOT)/Work.py" by the path till Work.py : "/Users/user/Downloads/Python/Work.py". But still it persisted on the same error. So the question is how to make Xcode run a python code given the issues I encountered ?

Thanks !

Comment: hay bro I am facing same problem.... how did you get it fixed..?

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it by searching Work.py file and where I saved it. After that hit right click on the Work.py file and click on Get Info. Expand General: and then copy the text from Where:. Paste that in that Argument box and close the windows. Everything should work now.